# Groovy to fetch only specify file from various folders

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am running below groovy script to fetch dynamic values from aws s3 bucket.
And below script is working fine and it will fetch all objects like shown in below output. 
current output is

```
  test-bucket-name/test/folde1/1.war
  test-bucket-name/test/folder2/2.war
  test-bucket-name/test/folder3/3.txt
```

Where as I want to display only *.war files in the output from "test-bucket-name" folder like below.

```
1.war
2.war
```

My Script:

```
def command = 'aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket=test-bucket-name --output=text'
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode= proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

if (error) {
    println "Std Err: ${error}"
    println "Process exit code: ${exitcode}"
    return exitcode
}

return output.split()
```

Please let me know how to extract/display only war files from test-bucket-name folder.

Comment: You may add `output.split().findAll { it.endsWith('.war') }`, That is the simplest and easiest way to filter out entries that don't end with `*.war` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to filter the entries that end with `.war`. Then split every entry once again (with `/`) and pick the last element:

```
def input = '''test-bucket-name/test/folde1/1.war
  test-bucket-name/test/folder2/2.war
  test-bucket-name/test/folder3/3.txt'''

input
    .split()
    .findAll { it.endsWith('.war') }
    .collect { it.split('/') }
    .collect { it[-1] }
```